# Servlet class not found exception

Tags: java, html, eclipse, servlets

I'm trying to write a very simple servlet, and a HTML form's action uses the servlet.

This is my HTML form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Video</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    Object userSession = session.getAttribute("email");

if(userSession == null)
{
    out.println("Welcome to the MyTube, you are not logged in. <br /><br >");
    out.println("Please click the following to login: <a href=\"login.jsp\">here</a>");
    out.println("Or Click this to register: <a href=\"register.jsp\">here</a>");
}
else
{
    out.println("<form action=\"servletClass\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">");
    out.println("<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" />");
    out.println("<input type=\"submit\" />");
    out.println("</form>");
}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my servlet class:

```
public class uploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    String awsAccessKey = "WHOOOPS";
    String awsSecretKey = "WHOOOPS/YWPkmKfe";
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        boolean isMulti = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (isMulti) 
        {
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

            try 
            {
                FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
                while (iter.hasNext()) 
                {
                    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                    InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
                    if (item.isFormField()) 
                    {

                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        String fileName = item.getName();
                        if (fileName != null && fileName.length() > 0) 
                        {
                            S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials);

                            S3Object fileObject = new S3Object();
                            fileObject.setDataInputStream(inputStream);
                            fileObject.setContentLength(Integer.parseInt(request.getHeader("Content-Length")));
                            s3Service.putObject("vidvidbucket", fileObject);

                            //read stream of file uploaded

                            //store as a temporary file

                            //upload the file to s3
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {

            }
        }

        response.sendRedirect("location of the result page");
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyTubeServer</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletClass</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletClass</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletClass</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the eclipse settings:

[image]

I looked at other posts that you should also include the java file at your WEB-INF folder. But I keep getting classNotFoundException.

EDIT: The stacktrace indicates that the uploadServlet cannot be found, so I'm confused.

EDIT 2: After setting XML file for the servlet-class to servletClass.uploadServlet instead of servlet-class, but now I get the requested source, (X/Location%Of%The%File%Is%Not%Found) without any exceptions

[image]

Comment: There's no need for including the java source file in the WEB-INF folder, if that's what you mean.

Comment: This issue normally occurs when the servlet is not getting the class file, try again writing the full path of the uploadServlet.

Comment: The ClassNotFoundException will tell you what class it did not find. Learn how to read and understand exception trace.

Comment: Please edit the word 'Servler` to 'Servlet` in subject line . Thanks .

Comment: Thanks for your guys help!
@Nilsh, I looked at a few other posts, and what they were missing was the java source file at WEB-INF folder. I tried that solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Milesh, do you mean in servlet mapping, I should add /src/servletClass/uploadServlet?

Comment: @BhushanBhangale, the server is complaining the upload servlet isn't found, which is strange

Comment: Can you post screen for the error ?

Comment: What are you trying to hit in the server ?

Comment: What is `response.sendRedirect("location of the result page");` in your servlet code ?

Comment: Uh oh.... I think I forgot to change the location of the result page to something else, and I forgot about it. So it was left there, and I thought it was some valid error. Yes, this fixes it. I think all the answers were valid, it's just my stupidity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `web.xml` is incorrect. The image shows package hierarchy

[image]

So, It should be like this

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>servletClass</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servletClass.uploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Restart Tomcat

Second, Try giving context path in form action.

```
<%
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
%>

out.println("<form action=\""+contextPath+"/servletClass\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">");
```

EDIT:
I think now servlet is getting called but This is wrong

```
response.sendRedirect("location of the result page");
```

Change it to some valid `JSP` page.

Comment: Thanks for your help! ContextPath just returns to my index.jsp, I think that's what it does? When I added servletClass.uploadServlet, it just shows The requested source, (X/Location%Of%The%File%Is%Not%Found).

Comment: @user1157751: Can you upload error screen to the question ? with your new efforts as EDIT

Comment: I added a new screenshot with the new error, it is now a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: I don't think you need to add the context path , <form action="servletClass"/> is sufficient !

Comment: All the responses was correct, it was my stupidity that caused the error. Thank you guys for your help!!

Comment: @user1157751: you may accept the answer As I pin out the actual cause :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Try this in your web.xml :

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>servletClass</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servletClass.uploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Restart the server and check .

2) The cause of second error is this line :

```
 response.sendRedirect("location of the result page");
```

in your Servlet code . Please redirect to a proper available resource . For more , refer to the  [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) .

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried adding a "servletClass." before, but what I always get is "The requested source, (X/Location%Of%The%File%Is%Not%Found)".

Comment: Are you getting any exception now ? please paste the stackTrace here if that's the case.

Comment: No, I'm not getting any exceptions, but a warning in the console. WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyTubeServer' did not find a matching property.